# Android camera2 app where barcode detection is not working, despite face detection working as it should

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm trying to work with barcode scanning on android using Camera2. There is already others who have done stuff similar to this and I'm trying to make them work for me (which is not going too well to be honest).

I started by using the barcode scanning sample (google vision) for for the regular camera source  and then tried to combine it with stuff made by Ezequiel Adrian Minniti (he made it work with both camera and camera2). Ezequil made the face detector work and I'm trying to extend that to work with the barcode detector. I built it up almost exactly the same, but it's not working.

I can switch between using barcodeDetector and previewFaceDetector by just commenting away the one i don't want to use when I build the Camera2Source at the end of the createCameraSource method. When I use the previewFaceDetector everything is working just fine. The Log.d for every new item in the GraphicFaceTracker prints out just as it should. When I use the barcodeDetector I get no response from the detector. The camera preview works just as normal, but no graphical overlay, no printing for the new items in the BarcodeGraphicTracker, no indication at all that anything has been found. And no error related to this either...

The barcodes I'm scanning have been tried with the google vision example (using just camera, not camera2) so I don't think there should be an issue there. 
Can anyone help with finding the issue here? Why does face tracking work but not barcode tracking?

```
private void createCameraSource(){
    // A barcode detector is created to track barcodes.  An associated multi-processor instance
    // is set to receive the barcode detection results, track the barcodes, and maintain
    // graphics for each barcode on screen.  The factory is used by the multi-processor to
    // create a separate tracker instance for each barcode.


    BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(context).build();
    BarcodeTrackerFactory barcodeFactory = new BarcodeTrackerFactory();

    if (!barcodeDetector.isOperational()) {
        // Note: The first time that an app using the barcode or face API is installed on a
        // device, GMS will download a native libraries to the device in order to do detection.
        // Usually this completes before the app is run for the first time.  But if that
        // download has not yet completed, then the above call will not detect any barcodes
        // and/or faces.
        //
        // isOperational() can be used to check if the required native libraries are currently
        // available.  The detectors will automatically become operational once the library
        // downloads complete on device.
        Log.w(TAG, "Detector dependencies are not yet available.");

        // Check for low storage.  If there is low storage, the native library will not be
        // downloaded, so detection will not become operational.
        IntentFilter lowstorageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);
        boolean hasLowStorage = registerReceiver(null, lowstorageFilter) != null;

        if (hasLowStorage) {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.low_storage_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.w(TAG, getString(R.string.low_storage_error));
        }
    } else {
        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(barcodeFactory).build());
    }


    FaceDetector previewFaceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
            .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)
            .setMode(FaceDetector.FAST_MODE)
            .setProminentFaceOnly(true)
            .setTrackingEnabled(true)
            .build();

    if(previewFaceDetector.isOperational()) {
        previewFaceDetector.setProcessor(new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(new GraphicFaceTrackerFactory()).build());
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "FACE DETECTION NOT AVAILABLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


        mCameraSource = new Camera2Source.Builder(context, previewFaceDetector)
//        mCameraSource = new Camera2Source.Builder(context, barcodeDetector)
                .setFocusMode(Camera2Source.CAMERA_AF_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)
                .setFlashMode(Camera2Source.CAMERA_FLASH_ON)
                .setFacing(Camera2Source.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .build();

            startCameraSource();
}

private class GraphicFaceTrackerFactory implements MultiProcessor.Factory<Face> {
    @Override
    public Tracker<Face> create(Face face) {
        return new GraphicFaceTracker(mGraphicOverlay);
    }
}

private class BarcodeTrackerFactory implements MultiProcessor.Factory<Barcode> {
    @Override
    public Tracker<Barcode> create(Barcode barcode) {
        return new BarcodeGraphicTracker(mGraphicOverlay);
    }

}

private class GraphicFaceTracker extends Tracker<Face> {
    private GraphicOverlay mOverlay;

    GraphicFaceTracker(GraphicOverlay overlay) {
        mOverlay = overlay;
        mFaceGraphic = new FaceGraphic(overlay, context);
    }

    /**
     * Start tracking the detected face instance within the face overlay.
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewItem(int faceId, Face item) {
        mFaceGraphic.setId(faceId);
        Log.d(TAG, "GraphicFaceTracker new item");
    }

    /**
     * Update the position/characteristics of the face within the overlay.
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(FaceDetector.Detections<Face> detectionResults, Face face) {
        mOverlay.add(mFaceGraphic);
        mFaceGraphic.updateFace(face);
    }

    /**
     * Hide the graphic when the corresponding face was not detected.  This can happen for
     * intermediate frames temporarily (e.g., if the face was momentarily blocked from
     * view).
     */
    @Override
    public void onMissing(FaceDetector.Detections<Face> detectionResults) {
        mFaceGraphic.goneFace();
        mOverlay.remove(mFaceGraphic);
    }

    /**
     * Called when the face is assumed to be gone for good. Remove the graphic annotation from
     * the overlay.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDone() {
        mFaceGraphic.goneFace();
        mOverlay.remove(mFaceGraphic);
    }
}

private class BarcodeGraphicTracker extends Tracker<Barcode> {

    private GraphicOverlay mOverlay;
    private BarcodeGraphic mGraphic;

    BarcodeGraphicTracker(GraphicOverlay overlay) {
        mOverlay = overlay;
        mGraphic = new BarcodeGraphic(overlay);
    }

    /**
     * Start tracking the detected item instance within the item overlay.
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewItem(int id, Barcode item) {
        mGraphic.setId(id);
        Log.d(TAG, "BarcodeGraphicTracker new item");
    }

    /**
     * Update the position/characteristics of the item within the overlay.
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detectionResults, Barcode item) {
        mOverlay.add(mGraphic);
        mGraphic.updateItem(item);
    }

    /**
     * Hide the graphic when the corresponding object was not detected.  This can happen for
     * intermediate frames temporarily, for example if the object was momentarily blocked from
     * view.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMissing(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detectionResults) {
        mOverlay.remove(mGraphic);
    }

    /**
     * Called when the item is assumed to be gone for good. Remove the graphic annotation from
     * the overlay.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDone() {
        mOverlay.remove(mGraphic);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, do you see *Detector dependencies are not yet available*?

Comment: @AlexCohn no, I don't. should that appear in the debug console?